# How to remove blank strings from values in the getOptions method? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement filter functionality for a table in React. Basically this is a multi-select.

This is my Dropdown Code

```
<Select
              placeholder='ALL'
              style={{ width: '80%', marginBottom: '20px' }}
              onChange={(entry) => {
              this.setState({ fnselect: entry });
              this.onFilteredChange(
                entry.map((o) => {
                  return o.value;
                }),
                'FirstName'
              );
            }}
              value={this.state.fnselect}
              multi={true} // eslint-disable-line
              options={this.getOptions('FirstName')}
            />
```

This is the getOptions method.

```
getOptions(propertyName) {
    return this.state.data.reduce((accum, elem, i) => {
      const accumulator = [...accum];
      if(!accumulator.some(e => e.value === elem[propertyName])) { // eslint-disable-line
        accumulator.push({
          id: i,
          value: elem[propertyName],
          label: elem[propertyName]
        });
      }
      return accumulator;
    }, []);
  }
```

Basically this.state.data has values for all fields/dropdowns. I want to remove empty string values for all dropdowns. I don't want to modify the this.state.data. I want to do this in the getOptions method.

I want to remove blank string data of that particular filter from getOptions method. How can I achieve this?

For further clarity

```
options={this.getOptions('FirstName')}// Here 'FirstName' is a field name in this.state.data
```

Can someone help me to eliminate the blank strings in the dropdown values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter` to remain only strings that are not empty.

```js
const arr = ['1', '2', '', '4'];

console.log(arr.filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: but try to understand my returned variable is an object, not a plain array